# How to formulate discrete-time resource scheduling into problem?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I'm new to linear programming and trying to develop an ILP model around a problem I'm trying to solve.

My problem is analogous to a machine resource scheduling problem.  I have a set of binary variables to represent paired-combinations of machines with a discrete-time grid.  Job A takes 1 hour, Job B takes 1 hr and 15 minutes, so the time grid should be in 15 minute intervals.  Therefore Job A would use 4 time units, and Job B would use 5 time units.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to express a constraint such that when a job is assigned to a machine, the units it occupies are sequential in the time variable.  Is there an example of how to model this constraint?  I'm using PuLP if it helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement the constraint:

```
x(t-1) = 0 and x(t) = 1 ==> x(t)+...+x(t+n-1) = n
```

One way is:

```
x(t)+...+x(t+n-1) >= n*(x(t)-x(t-1))
```

Notes:

1. you need to repeat this constraint for each `t`.
2. A slightly better version is:

   ```
   x(t+1)+...+x(t+n-1) >= (n-1)*(x(t)-x(t-1))
   ```
3. There is also a disaggregated version of this constraint that may help performance (depending on the solver: some solvers can do this disaggregation automatically).
4. Things can become interesting near the beginning and end of the planning period. E.g. machine started at `t=-1`.

Update:

A different approach is just to limit the "start" of a job to 1. I.e. allow only the combination

```
 x(j,t-1) = 0 and x(j,t) = 1
```

for a given job j. This can be handled in a similar way:

```
 start(j,t) >= x(j,t)-x(j,t-1)
 sum(t, start(j,t)) <= 1
 0 <= start(j,t) <= 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  What makes the #2 slightly better version an improvement?

Comment: The slightly smaller coefficient for `x(t-1)`.  A bit nit-picking on my side.